# Retain quotation marks in Zend .ini config

Tags: zend-framework, configuration

I am building a website and I require quotation marks in a configuration value.

Example:

```
convert_arg = -resize "1000x1000>" -strip -trim +repage -density 72x72 -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -quality 70
```

This particular configuration item is the command-line arguments to call Imagemagick's convert utility. The quotation marks tell the command-line not to consider '>' as the pipe command. However, Zend appears to strip these characters from the value, so it tries to pipe the subsequent error to a file called -strip.

Can this be disabled or worked around? Thanks.

Comment: So Zend Config Ini uses PHP's parse_ini_file and there does not appear to be any way to escape quotation marks.

Subsequent Googling came up this this very dirty hack: http://missioncriticallabs.com/blog/2009/08/double-quotation-marks-in-php-ini-files/

Is this it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this question hasn't been answered in a while, I figure I will respond with my work-around. It's not ideal, but it works and is not too difficult to implement.

It involves declaring a constant which will represent the quotation mark, as Zend_Config (Which uses the `parse_ini_file()` function) will interpret PHP constants.

In www/index.php we declare the constant:

```
// Define _Q to be a quotation mark
defined('_Q') || define('_Q', '"');
```

In application.ini we use the constant in place of quotation marks:

```
my.config.key = "my config value can now contain " _Q "quotation marks" _Q "!"
```

So now, in your code, the value of `my.config.key` is now:

> my config value can now contain "quotation marks"!